# Changing document title is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, title

I'm trying to add the notification number to the title in a function, but it won't work. This is my code:

```
  var docTitle = document.title;

  document.title = "".docTitle." (".$(".loadnot").html().")";
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In JavaScript you should use `+` for concatenating not `.`.

```
document.title = docTitle + "(" + $(".loadnot").html() + ")";
```

Answer (score 4):

Or even better:

```
document.title += " ("+$(".loadnot").html()+")";
```

Answer (score 0):

check this:

```
window.top.document.title = "Your Title";
```

Answer (score 0):

If none of the answers above fit then is simply:

Some Javascript server side is blocking the changing of the document title.

Check how -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/27847787/16759195

All you have to do is to add to your code the following lines:

```
Object.defineProperty(document, 'title', {
  enumerable: true,
  configurable: true,
  writable: true,
  value: document.title
});
```